# Only my If statement is working but my elif isn't

Tags: python

So I created if and elif statements my if statement is working is the condition is met however, if the condition is met in the If statement but not the elif statement the code stops running and gives me and error.

```
bb = ["a","c","d"]
dd = ["e","f","g"]
cc = [1,2,3]
ee = [4,5,6]

partyname = input()
partyname = partyname.lower()

if partyname == bb[bb.index(partyname)]:
    cc.pop(cc.index(cc[bb.index(partyname)]))
    bb.pop(bb.index(partyname))

elif partyname == dd[dd.index(partyname)]:
    ee.pop(ee.index(ee[dd.index(partyname)]))
    dd.pop(dd.index(partyname))

print(bb)
print(cc)
print(dd)
print(ee)
```

for example the code works if I input a or c but does not work if I input e or f.

### Here is the input and the error message:
e

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
7 partyname = partyname.lower()
8
----> 9 if partyname == bb[bb.index(partyname)] or partyname == dd[dd.index(partyname)] :
10     if partyname == bb[bb.index(partyname)]:
11         cc.pop(cc.index(cc[bb.index(partyname)]))

ValueError: 'e' is not in list

Comment: for code formatting use ` instead of '

Comment: could You show what error this code gives Your?

Comment: Is there a reason you didnt include the error message?

Comment: The check `partyname == bb[bb.index(partyname)]` is pretty pointless. If `partyname` is in `bb`, then `bb[bb.index(partyname)]` _must_ be `partyname`. And if it's not, you get an exception. Instead, you should probably check `if partyname in bb`.

Comment: basically the first if will always evaluate to true if partyname is in the list

Comment: I added the error message sorry first timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First its better to use the operator `in` to check if `partyname` is in the `bb` list.

```
bb = ["a","c","d"]
dd = ["e","f","g"]
cc = [1,2,3]
ee = [4,5,6]

partyname = input().lower()

if partyname in bb:
    cc.pop(cc.index(cc[bb.index(partyname)]))
    bb.pop(bb.index(partyname))

elif partyname in dd:
    ee.pop(ee.index(ee[dd.index(partyname)]))
    dd.pop(dd.index(partyname))

print(bb)
print(cc)
print(dd)
print(ee)
```

Second what is the purpose of `cc` and `ee`?
If you want to link a string to a number you can use [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
bb_dict = {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
dd_dict = {'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6}

partyname = input().lower()

if partyname in bb:
    bb_dict.pop(partyname)

elif partyname in dd:
    dd_dict.pop(partyname)

print(bb_dict)
print(dd_dict)
```

Comment: its for a seating thing im creating basically bb is the name of the party and cc is its corresponding number. Thank you when I used in it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The check `partyname == bb[bb.index(partyname)]` is pretty pointless.

Either, `partyname` is in `bb`, then `bb[bb.index(partyname)]` must be equal to `partyname`; or it is not in the list, then `index` raises an Exception.

Instead, you should just check `if partyname in bb` and analogously for the `elif`.

---

Similarly, the line `cc.pop(cc.index(cc[bb.index(partyname)]))` is extremely complicated and inefficient and can probably be simplified a bit. Lets see what it does:

- `cc[bb.index(partyname)]` gets you the element of `cc` that corresponds to the `partyname` in `bb`
- `cc.pop(cc.index(...))` gets you the index of that element and pops it

You could just use `remove` instead of `pop` to remove the element itself instead of getting the index, but you could probably also just use a `dict` using the elements of `bb` as keys and those of `dd` as values (and another for `cc` and `ee` for the `elif`).

```
bb_cc = {"a": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3}
dd_ee = {"e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6}

partyname = input().lower()

if partyname in bb_cc:
    del bb_cc[partyname]
elif partyname in dd_ee:
    del dd_ee[partyname]

print(bb_cc)
print(dd_ee)
```

Comment: thank you for the help! the code is now working